# Windows batch file and processing paths with an ampersand

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, ampersand

I'm a novice with coding windows batch files, and am struggling to get this code to handle ampersands.

The batch file is designed to create thumbs from images in one folder tree, into another folder tree using imagemagick. 
All works well until there is an ampersand in the path. Double quoting sorts this out for most commands, but when it hits 'if not exist "%thumbpath%"', it falls over if there is an ampersand in %thumbpath%.

I've tried using the short 8.3 version of the path, and while it doesn't fall over, it also doesn't return true if the file doesn't exist.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
cd /D "%~dp0"
call :processFiles
pause
goto :eof

:processFiles
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do call :processFile "%%f", "%%~nxf", "%%~pf", "%%~df"


:processFile
:: parameters 1=full path, 2=filename, 3=path(no drive no file), 4=drive
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "source=%~1"
set fileName=%~2
set "folder=%~4%~3"

:: replace media path with thumbs folder
set "folder=%folder:\media\=\media\thumbs\%"

:: create the directory tree if required
if not exist "%folder%" md "%folder%"

set "thumbpath=%folder%%fileName%"

:: the following line causes an error when there is an ampersand in %thumbpath%
if not exist "%thumbpath%" (
    magick "%source%" -resize 250x250 -unsharp  0x6+0.5+0 "%thumbpath%"
)

exit /b
```

Comment: `set fileName=%~2` is missing double quotes unlike the other `set` lines. I suspect that as the problem as `&` would end the `set` command and start a new command.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll add the quotes to that line just to be safe, but its not what's causing this issue... the ampersand is not in any of the file names, just some of the directory names.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `exit /b` after the line of the `for /R` which allows the code of the called `:processFiles` to continue down into `:processFile`. Doubt you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Confession time... I had a line in my code echo %thumbpath% just before the magick line. This was the culprit as I didn't double-quote %thumbpath%.

Comment: You could also solve it by using delayed expansion. `echo !thumbpath!` works without quotes